# Haven't access to class in custom class stack implementation

Tags: c#

My classes structure looks like:

```
public abstract class LogicalTreeNode {
}

public class LogicalOperator:LogicalTreeNode {
    public readonly string value;

    public LogicalOperator(string value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

}

public class ConditionResult:LogicalTreeNode {
    public readonly bool value;

    public ConditionResult(bool value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}`
```

I'm trying to implement some logic with using `Stack<LogicalTreeNode>`. I need standart stack's methods and my own `TryPush(LogicalTreeNode)`, that will work recursive (for some cases). So i do that:

```
public class Stack<LogicalTreeNode> : Stack {
    public void TryPush(LogicalTreeNode logicalTreeNode) {
        /*Some logic */
        this.TryPush(new ConditionResult(false));
    }
}
```

And i get `cannot convert ConditionResult to LogicalTreeNode`. What am i doing from? TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created a custom class `Stack` generic to `System.Collections.Stack` which accepts `Stack<LogicalTreeNode>`.

Change your code to this-

```
public class Stack<T> : Stack
{
    public void TryPush(LogicalTreeNode logicalTreeNode)
    {
        /*Some logic */
        this.TryPush(new ConditionResult(false));
    }
}
```

If you specifically want your class to be instantiated with only certain type like- `LogicalTreeNode` in this case, then you have to do like this-

```
public class MyStack<T> where T : LogicalTreeNode
{
    public void TryPush(LogicalTreeNode logicalTreeNode)
    {
        /*Some logic */
        this.TryPush(new ConditionResult(false));
    }
}
```

If you need to inherit from `System.Collections.Stack` class and also restrict the type to `LogicalTreeNode`, then do like this-

```
public class MyStack<T> : System.Collections.Stack : where T : LogicalTreeNode
{
    public void TryPush(LogicalTreeNode logicalTreeNode)
    {
        /*Some logic */
        this.TryPush(new ConditionResult(false));
    }
}
```

Also, as a good practice, don't name your class as `Stack` as it is a C# keyword. Use a different name.

References:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-classes

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters

Comment: Got it. Thank you.